# CreateTexture2D() fails when using DXGI_FORMAT_YUY2 as Format

Tags: directx-10

When `D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC` contains the following:

```
textureDesc.Width               = 1920 * 2;
textureDesc.Height              = 1080 * 2;
textureDesc.MipLevels           = 1;
textureDesc.ArraySize           = 1;
textureDesc.Format              = DXGI_FORMAT_YUY2;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count    = 1;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality  = 0;
textureDesc.Usage               = D3D10_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
textureDesc.BindFlags           = D3D10_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags      = D3D10_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
textureDesc.MiscFlags           = 0;
```

the ID3D10Device::CreateTexture2D() fails.
But, if I change Format to `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM`, the ID3D10Device::CreateTexture2D() succeeds. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: I know DirectX can output comments about error to stderr or stdout if you set  D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag.

Comment: @Unick, you should have written that as an answer (you still can). After providing the D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag I received an error: Device does not support the format YUY2.

Comment: You should be using DirectX 11 rather than legacy Direct3D 10 in any case. Most ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL`` 10.0 or later hardware supports ``NV12``, ``420_OPAQUE``, and ``YUY2``. 10level9 hardware usually only supports ``420_OPAQUE``.

Comment: You also need to be using the DirectX 11.1 Runtime or later. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205075.aspx) for details on format support requirements.

Comment: @ Chuck Walbourn, you were right, the same call in DirectX 11 succeeds. Now I have to find a way to send that YUV texture to the render target in RGBA format....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, that DirectX can output comments about error to stderr or stdout if you set D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag. Looks like it will help you to find the reason of failed.